# OnClick event won't respond

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick, google-maps-markers

I have a button and I have set it to respond on an OnClick event. So when the button is clicked, the code below is getting executed. I want the button to add a marker to the user's current location when it's clicked, but what happens instead when I click the button is that the application closes. The OnClick button's name is `Add_Marker`. Thanks

```
public void Add_Marker(View x)
{
   gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   LocationManager locationManager = 
      (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
   Location myLocation =    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   double latidude= myLocation.getLatitude();
   double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
   LatLng latlng= new LatLng(latidude,longitude);
   gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
   gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
   gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new   
   LatLng(latidude,longitude)).title("You are here"));
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    ... 11 more
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    at com.example.demomap.THEMAP.Add_Marker(THEMAP.java:109)
02-24 16:45:48.717: E/AndroidRuntime(17503):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please also post your logcat and the code related to the button. Thanks.

Comment: also paste how you are calling the onClick event.

Comment: Hey, I edited my post do you guys have nay idea of why is this happening ? Thanks for your help

Comment: please post your xml layout or the method where you are assigning the onCLick Method

Comment: public void Add_marker is the method and here is the xml for the button

Comment: xml for button       <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnmarker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
  
    android:onClick="Add_Marker"
    android:text="add marker" />